# How to make div height 100% of his parent?

Tags: html, css

I need to make my four columns classes to 100% height of container height. But I didn't find a example, which works. How should I add css for container and four columns classes to make the children div height the same like father?

[image]

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="four columns">
      <h4 class="text-white">{{$restaurant->restourant_name}}</h4>
      <h6 class="text-white"> <b>{{$restaurant->restourant_address}}</b></h6>
      <h6 class="text-white">Tel. <b>{{$restaurant->restaurant_phone}}</b></h6>
      <h6 onclick="openMap();" class="text-green" style="cursor:pointer"><b>{{ trans('restaurant.map') }}</b></h6>
    </div>

    <div class="four columns" style="display:flex; " >
      <div class="two columns" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:flex; margin: auto; ">
        <div style="width:20%; margin: auto;">
          <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="img/clockWhite.png">
        </div>
        <div style="width:80%;">
          <div style="height:50%; border-bottom: 4px dotted  ">
         {{ trans('restaurant.work_hours') }}
          </div>
          <div style="height:50%; white-space:nowrap">
          @if ($restaurant->work_start == null )
           <b>{{ trans('restaurant.closed') }}</b>
          @else
            {{substr($restaurant->work_start,0,-3)}} - {{substr($restaurant->work_end,0,-3)}}
          @endif
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="two columns" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:flex; margin: auto; ">
        <div style="width:20%; margin: auto;">
          <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="img/clockWhite.png">
        </div>
        <div style="width:80%;">
          <div style="height:50%; border-bottom: 4px dotted white;">
         {{ trans('restaurant.delivery_hours') }}
          </div>
          <div style="height:50%; white-space:nowrap">
          @if ($restaurant->delivery_start == null )
           <b>{{ trans('restaurant.no_delivery') }}</b>
          @else
            {{substr($restaurant->delivery_start,0,-3)}} - {{substr($restaurant->delivery_end,0,-3)}}
          @endif
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

.container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 20px;
box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
width: 100%;
float: left;
box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` property to the column class.

```
.column,
.columns {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a jsfiddle demo ?.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/77mvztp0/, but expand the result screen to max, to see how it looks.

Comment: @TomasBajoras Could you please add the `display:flex` Property to the container div ?. and also please remove the the flex and height property from the class called `class="four columns"`. please see the demo 

   https://jsfiddle.net/77mvztp0/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to achieve that your columns should have height equal to container's height, other than making it a 100% you can set height for both  container and column in pixels e.g. `height:75px;`

Comment: I can't use pixels, because when the containers will be not responsive.

Comment: use `height` for column and `max-height` container for responsive media, or you can simply add margins to fill the gap ?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... You want the columns inside the div to be as high as the div they are in?

If you want: here's an ugly solution in Javascript. Add some ID's to your divs, and use this code:

```
<script>
    function load() {
        var element = document.getElementById('container');
        var resizeThis = document.getElementById('setThisToContainerHeight');
        resizeThis.style.height = element.offsetHeight+'px';
    }
    window.onload = load;
</script>
```

NB: Don't think this is recommended way, but at least it works...

---

Edit:

By the way: If you have a fixed size on the parent div, you could add it in the CSS and then set height 100%. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77mvztp0/2/

The only thing I've done in this fiddle is to add an id: "container" to the parent div, and an id: "makeMeBigger" to the children div. Then I added height 200px on parent and height 100% on child!

Edit END.

---

NEW Edit:

Have you tried this:

https://jsfiddle.net/77mvztp0/3/

What I've done here is to add an overflow property to parent div and then setting height to 100% on children:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.four-columns {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Yes, I want that the columns div be inside the container div, because now the columns div height is depend on the text length.

Comment: Read my updated post, I think if you set i.e. height of your parent div to be i.e. 200px, and then setting "Height: 100%;" of child div, it will fix your problems! :) Given that you have a fixed size of parent div!

Comment: yes, but i can't set parent div height with pixels, because when it will be NOT responsive :/ because on small screen parent div height is bigger, than on pc screen.

Comment: Have  you tried the javascript solution? NB: that has to be added at the end of HTML or in a separate script (but still added last in HTML) so that the HTML has loaded when trying to set the height.

Comment: Yes, but it's not good decision to use js, it should be made with css. And onLoad function is not good, because this function calls one time, but if I change portrait and landscape mode on mobile, I will lose responsive.

Comment: Check my new solution using overflow and positioning! :)

Comment: yes, it's nice. But now the columns not breaking on the small screen, try to reduce my fiddle and yours. But thanks, for the help :)